Can I add color gradients to plotly stacked bar chart?
I have a px stacked bar chart of 20 journal titles across the x-axis and the breakdown of access types within each journal as stacked segments. The access type data is across multiple years. Is it possible to encode both the access types AND the year by color? If possible, I would like to add gradients of the color code to represent years.
MWE
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

d = {'Journal': ['Journal One', 'Journal One', 'Journal One', 'Journal One', 'Journal One', 'Journal One', 'Journal One'],
     'Access': ['Green', 'Green', 'Closed', 'Green', 'Closed', 'Green', 'Closed'],
     'Year': [2020, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023],
     'Count': [1, 1, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fig = px.bar(df, x='Journal', y='Count', color='Access', text_auto=True,
            category_orders={'Access': ["Closed", "Green"]},
            color_discrete_map={
                "Closed": "#AB63FA",
                "Green": "#2CA02C"},
           title = f'Journal Titles by Access status and Year' )

fig.show()



Am I able to specify gradients or transparency levels for the green and purple by Year to help distinguish the different data within color blocks? Is it possible to add two color encodings? Or is there a better way to show all this?

I believe there is only one uniform transparency setting in plotly.express. It is possible to extract by attribute in a graph object and then further graph it by year in a loop process. The transparency is set and then subtracted in a loop process. Please modify this to what you intend. Also, I'm making duplicate legend items into a single item.
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

for a in df['Access'].unique():
    dfa = df.query('Access == @a')
    opacity = 1.0
    colors = '#2CA02C' if a == 'Green' else '#AB63FA'
    for y in dfa['Year'].unique():
        dff = dfa.query('Year == @y')
        opacity -= 0.1
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            x=dff['Journal'],
            y=dff['Count'],
            marker=dict(color=colors, opacity=opacity),
            name=a,
            text=dff['Count'],
            legendgroup=a,
        ))

# Make duplicate legend items unique
names = set()
fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda trace:
        trace.update(showlegend=False)
        if (trace.name in names) else names.add(trace.name))

fig.update_layout(legend_title_text='Access', height=500, barmode='stack')

fig.show()



Thanks, this would give inconsistent results if an Access type didn't have data for a particular year. For example, the green 2 looks lighter than the purple 4, even though both are from 2023, because purple (Closed) didn't have data for 2020 and thus didn't get the opacity decremented by one step.
I could modify to provide a year-specific offset that always subtracts a constant amount for each year.
